# How to manipulate the print statements from files?

Tags: java, file

I am trying to do a program, and this is what i have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class WebberProject1
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("portlandvip.txt"));

(scanner.hasNext())
{
String firstName = scanner.next();
String lastName = scanner.next();

System.out.println(" " + firstName + " " + lastName);            
}
 }
}
```

The output of this program looks like this:

```
Loras Tyrell
 5 Club
 Margaery Tyrell
 8 Box
 Roslin Frey
 2 Box
 Sansa Stark
 2 Club
 Jon Snow
```

and the file looks like this:

```
Loras Tyrell 5 Club
Margaery Tyrell 8 Box
Roslin Frey 2 Box
Sansa Stark 2 Club
Jon Snow 5 Club
Edmure Tully 3 Box
Joffrey Baratheon 20 Court
Stannis Baratheon 4 Club
Jaime Lannister 2 Box
Cersei Lannister 1 Court
Beric Dondarrion 8 Court
Balon Greyjoy 16 Box
Olenna Tyrell 4 Court
Mace Tyrell 5 Box
Tyrion Lannister 2 Club
Sandor Clegane 2 Court
Gregor Clegane 6 Club
Samwell Tarly 3 Club
Petyr Baelish 6 Court
```

My question is, how do you remove the "5 club", "8 box", etc parts from the program's output?

Comment: call scanner.next() two more times in the loop after the print statement

Comment: i am not following, would it look something like this? System.out.println(" " + firstName + " " + lastName);     scanner.next()                                                  scanner.next()

Comment: @user3479350 YOu can read whole line and split that line on whitespaces. Print the info you want.

Comment: scanner class by default takes spaces and new lines as delimeters. scanner.next() reads a token (as a string) so, 5 and club are also read as tokens that gets printed.

Comment: @user3479350 yes this will work but it is not the best approach.

Comment: maxx777, thank you, that seemed to work

Comment: @user3479350 see the two answers below, for better approach.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can read whole line and split that line on whitespaces. Print the info you want.

See [String#split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Something like below

```
(scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
     // Split the line and return array of String
     String[] line = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");
     // get you info
     // print your info


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading first name and last name, you can skip rest of the line using `nextLine()`

```
(scanner.hasNext()){
  String firstName = scanner.next();
  String lastName = scanner.next();

  System.out.println(" " + firstName + " " + lastName);            
  scanner.nextLine();
}
```